# Get index for multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to get an index of a multidimensional and output it as a variable. I know this is very simple but I am struggling with it.

For example given the following:

```
[1]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(24) "What is your first name?"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(6) "f_name"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(12) "demographics"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(23) "What is your last name?"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(6) "l_name"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(12) "demographics"
  }
[3]=>
  array(11) {
    ["field_label"]=>
    string(32) "Researcher who took measurements"
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(17) "weight_researcher"
    ["identifier"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["options"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["form_name"]=>
    string(6) "weight"
  }
```

I want to find the index for the first element that has a form_name of "weight" (#3)

Comment: You should start here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a foreach and an if inside it:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
               //  ^ here resides the key of the parent array
    if($value['form_name'] == 'weight') { // if form name is weight
        echo $key; // echo the key
        break; // then stop on first occurence
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column`:

```
$key = array_search('weight', array_column($array, 'form_name'));
```

For multiple keys:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($array, 'form_name'), 'weight');
```